# How can I formulate this query in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this MYSQL query and require to formulate this using Eloquent in Laravel4.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee.Name, Employee.Id FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Team ON Employee.Id = Team.EmployeeId AND Team.TeamId = 1;
```

1. How can I add an `AND` clause on the `JOIN` in Laravel.
2. How can I add a DISTINCT to the SELECT in Laravel 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your Employee model with convention or proper `$table` connection  and then:

```
Employee::select(array(DB::raw('DISTINCT `Employee`.`Name`'), 'Employee.Id'))
    ->leftJoin('Team', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('Employee.id', '=', 'Team.EmployeeId')
                     ->on('Team.id', '=', DB::raw(1));
            })
    ->get();
```

If you want to use just `Query Builder`(Fluent) then replace `Employee::` with `DB::table('Employee')->`.

**Notes**:

- `DB::raw()` instructs Laravel not to put
  backtics there.
- By passing a closure to `join` methods you can add more join conditions to it, `on()` will add `AND` condition and `orOn()` will add `OR` condition.

Comment: Is there a way to see the SQL generated ?

Comment: @Fractaliste, instead of `->get();` use `->toSql();`  This will return the raw SQL query.